# Another expression for "drinking behavior" or "drinking habits"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

> In other words, a member’s drinking behavior is influenced by observing his peers’ drinking behavior.

To avoid repetition of *drinking* in this sentence, I need either one word for *drinking behavior* or another expression except for *drinking habits*.

Comment: "In other words, a member  is influenced by his peers drinking behavior. ". Would this sentence be unclear in the context?

Comment: *"In other words, a member's drinking behavior is influenced by observing **that of** his peers"*. I find it hard to believe English would have a single word for this concept.

Comment: Josh61 yes indeed. i want to pemphasize the drinking behavior of the member rathar than that of the peers

Comment: Ok, so @FumbleFingers suggestion may well fit your context!!!

Comment: @Sarra: It might be useful as *writing advice*, but that's Off Topic anyway, and it doesn't address the [single-word-request](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) question you seem to be asking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: At first i was looking for a single-word for my expression, that's why I requested a "single-word."  Anyway, I have edited my question.

Comment: Depending on the larger context many of the published synonyms of [behavior](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/behavior?s=t) or [habit](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/habits) will do.

Comment: @Sarra: Even after your edit, it's still not clear to me exactly what you mean by "drinking behaviour". Is it *the way someone drinks* (how often, how much, how fast, what type of drink, etc.), or *the way they behave when drunk?* Or both? Some people have a lower tolerance for alcohol, so it might be part of their "behaviour" to fall asleep after the first pint, but that probably wouldn't be affected by observing what others do.

Comment: Members' drinking habits generally follow the "[monkey see, monkey do](http://www.thetownsound.com/uploads/8/1/9/2/8192255/1414800023.png)" principle.

Answer (score 2):

**In other words, a member’s drinking behavior is influenced by observing his peers’ *[conduct](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conduct).***

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1 The manner in which a person behaves, especially in a
>   particular place or situation:
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

The context provides sufficient information concerning the scope of the conduct.

Answer (score 0):

"Attitude towards drinking" maybe? So something along the lines of:

In other words, a member's drinking behavior is influenced by observing his peers' attitude towards drinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try "use of alcohol" for the latter instance.  And don't forget the apostrophe in **peers'**.